# Cylindrical coordinates: $\iiint (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dxdydz$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Show that

$$ I= \iiint_S (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dxdydz = \frac{2^{10} a^5 k}{75} \left(1 + \frac{k^2}{3} \right), a>0, k>0$$

where $S$ is the region bounded by the cilinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2ax$ and the upper and lower sections of the cone $z^2 = k^2(x^2 + y^2)$.

**My attempt:**

$$
I = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^a \int_{-kr}^{kr} r(r^2 + z^2) dz dr d\theta
$$

using cylindrical coordinates, but I couldn't find the given value of this integral.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Do you know separation of variables and that integration is linear?

Comment: yes, what is the point?

Comment: 1. Your limits for $r$ are not OK (as written, you have $x^{2} + y^{2} = a^{2}$ as bounding cylinder), but 2. Can you say why you are unable to evaluate the integral as written (since that should be "easy")?

Comment: Ok, so what should be the limits for $r$? And it is asked to do this using cilindrical coordinates.

Comment: That you just have to integrate a polynomial: $I = \int_{-pi/2}^{pi/2} d\theta( \int_0^a r^3 dr +\int_0^a  r dr  \int_{-kr}^{kr}z^2 dz) $

Comment: ok, but we still have an answer "in function of" $\pi$ and we don't have $\pi$ at this answer. By the way, I think you forgot $\int_{-kz}^{kz} 1 dz \int_0^a r^3 dr$

Comment: Yes, I forgot it.

Comment: ok, so evalue your integral and tell me if you could find the answer (I mean, the given value of the integral). You probably got the same as mine (if we did everything correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cylinderical coordinates, Mathematica evaluates the following integral as
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2 a \cos \theta } \int_{-kr}^{kr} (r^2 + z^2) r dz dr d\theta = \frac{1024}{225} a^5 k \left(k^2+3\right)$$
I suppose you made error in the bounds of $r$ since center of cylinder is $(a, 0)$ and [polar equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=omg%20just%20polar%20plot%20r%20=%202cos%28theta%29) of circle with center $(a, 0)$ with radius $a$ is $r = 2a \cos(\theta)$

Also on rectangular coordinates the following code on Mathematica produces same value

> `Integrate[
>    x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, 0, 2 a}, {y, -Sqrt[2 a x - x^2], 
>     Sqrt[2 a x - x^2]}, {z, -Sqrt[k^2 (x^2 + y^2)], 
>     Sqrt[k^2 (x^2 + y^2)]}, Assumptions :> {a > 0, k > 0}]`

Comment: I noted this before, but thank you very much for your explanation